# How to create a diagonal matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have an excel file which contains 250 sheets( 1st sheet contains 250 rows and 11 columns,2nd sheet contains 249 rows and 11 columns, 3rd sheet contains 248 rows and 11 columns and so on). I need only the values of 11th column from all sheets for creating diagonal matrix. I think , First I have to import 11th column values from excel file to R . Based on these values I have to create a diagonal matrix . Please help me

Comment: Some very rudimentary Google searches turn up `read.xls` in the `gdata` package and `diag` for creating diagonal matrices.

Comment: Edited question to better reflect the problem statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you are describing, you really want a triangular matrix, and I will show how to create an upper triangular matrix:

Step 1: create a matrix to receive results:

```
mat <- matrix(NA, ncol=250, nrow=250)
```

Step 2: get a function to read n-th sheet's  the n rows in the 11-th column

```
require(gdata) # to get read.xls or use an equivalent that works with your unstated OS
               # you do need a Perl interpreter and a proper .pm file
```

Step 3: loop over the 250 sheets and put in the matrix rows

```
for(idx in 1:250 ) { 
   intemp <- read.xls(xlsfilename, sheet = idx )
   mat[ idx, (251-idx):250] <- intemp[1:idx, 11]
         }
```

There are lots of way this could fail. The obvious one is indexing past the end of the range of data that comes in from the sheets

Answer (score 21):

For some strange reason google query for "r diagonal matrix" points me to this page, thus i think it is reasonable to answer this question here.

The most basic way to do this in R is to use function diag:

```
diag(1, 4, 4)
```

gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1
```

Comment: This general formula is useful for putting whatever you want in the diagonal, but if you just want a simple 4-by-4 identity matrix, you can simply write `diag(4)`.

Comment: as does `diag(1,4)`, (which allows a digit other than 1 along the diagonal, but saves two whole characters!)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ***Diagonal*** function from the *Matrix* library; just pass in the dimension and value (which seem to be what is in column 11 of your spreadsheet):

```
> library(Matrix)
> v = Diagonal(n=5, x=5.5)
> v
  5 x 5 diagonal matrix of class "ddiMatrix"
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]  5.5    .    .    .    .
  [2,]    .  5.5    .    .    .
  [3,]    .    .  5.5    .    .
  [4,]    .    .    .  5.5    .
  [5,]    .    .    .    .  5.5
```

(Note: *Matrix* needs to be explicitly imported via call to *Library*, though not separately installed because it seems to be included in the the R install)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried your code . Using your code how to get lower and upper triangle values i.e 11th column values from 250 sheets. These values are different in each sheet? Could you please explain?

Comment: from reading your Question, i am not certain how you wish to map your spreadsheet values to matrices in R. Perhaps the easiest way to proceed is to create the 'complete' matrix, then call tril() (lower triangular) or triu() on those to extract the triangular matrices.

Comment: @manjitha I do not think that you read the text offered by the questioner. You only read the term “diagonal” and that term was not an accurate description of the problem.